# A Regular Expression Which matches the sequence

Tags: c#, regex

The set of strings can be like these.

1) anyNoOfcharacters< anycharacter> anyNoOfcharacters . anyNoOfcharacters

2) anyNoOfcharacters < anychar > anyNoOfcharacters and an ' #' (as a last string )

3) anyNoOfcharacters " _ " anyNoOfcharacters and an " # "

4) anyNoOfcharacters and anyNoOfdigits followed by an " #"

Can there be a single REgex which can validate all of the above set of strings ?

This is what I have done so far...

```
 Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+[a-zA-Z0-9#.-] | [\b\w\d] |  ");
```

Can anyone please add conditions to the above pattern according to my requirements.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? Are you just asking for a single regex that matches all of those strings? If so, I think the answer is simply no.

Comment: Your requirements are pretty vague.  Are you wanting a regex that looks for the 5 exact strings you listed, or are these just examples of a much larger set?  If the latter, what parts of the strings vary?

Comment: @BrianRogers the set of strings are in between the lines of a document. Yes regex for only those five strings that I have listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirements, here is a regex that should match any one of the five exact strings you listed.  If this is not what you meant, then please clarify.

```
 Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(ads<r>_aimDate50ms\.Good)|(ads<t>Valid#)|(tactics_priorityT)|(tactics_SelectedADS#)|(ads3bValid#)");
```

**EDIT**

Your requirements are still very hand-wavy.  Let's try to define some specific rules.  I think maybe we want:

- one or more letters, followed by
- zero or more letters or numbers or underscores, followed by
- zero or one `#` character

-- OR --

- one or more letters, followed by
- zero or more letters or numbers or underscores, followed by
- exactly one `<` character, followed by
- exactly one letter, followed by
- exactly one `>` character, followed by
- one or more letters or numbers or underscores or `.` characters, followed by
- zero or one `#` character

Is this in the ballpark?  These rules will match your examples, yet they still may not be "correct".  This is what I mean when I say you need to be specific.  If you can describe clearly what the pattern is, then you can write a regex for it.  If you can't discern a set of rules to describe the pattern, then there isn't a way to turn it into a regex.

Can you update your question to list out the specific rules for the pattern now?  For every part of the pattern we need to know: what kind of character or characters are you expecting, and how many of them can appear in a row.  For example, zero or more, one or more, exactly one, etc.

**EDIT 2**

Based on your updated question, I think I can take a shot.  When you say "anyNoOfCharacters" you did not clarify what KIND of characters.  But if you meant literally ANY kind character, including spaces, punctuation, etc. then the regex would not be very useful because it would match just about everything.  So I am going to assume that you meant only letters in that case.

Here are your rules (along with my assumption about "anyNoOfCharacters") translated into regex:

1. `[A-Za-z]*<.>[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]*`
2. `[A-Za-z]*<.>[A-Za-z]*#`
3. `[A-Za-z]*_[A-Za-z]*#`
4. `[A-Za-z0-9]*#`

To get this into a single regex, you can just combine the terms by putting parenthesis `(` `)` around each rule and adding a `|` between them.  Thus we have:

```
 Regex pattern = new Regex(@"([A-Za-z]*<.>[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]*)|([A-Za-z]*<.>[A-Za-z]*#)|([A-Za-z]*_[A-Za-z]*#)|([A-Za-z0-9]*#)");
```

I'm guessing this is close, but still maybe not quite there.  Do you have enough where you can take this and refine it to your needs?  If not, then please clarify more.

Comment: Exactly means this is not what I mean. Those are just examples I have given, a REgex for the pattern that I want...

Comment: So then you need to describe what the pattern is that you want to match.  It is impossible to tell what the pattern is from the examples you have given.

Comment: the pattern includes.."Start with alphabets, next there can be digits" it should match " </w/d>_/w." also should validate " </w/d>_./w " followed by an #.As shown in above examples

Comment: Getting warmer, but this is still pretty vague.  Can you list out all the specific rules?  I will update my answer to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: I've updated my answer again based on your new rules, and my assumption about what you meant by "anyNoOfCharacters".

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[^\s]+");
```

based on your comment try this

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?:[^\s]*[_#\.][^\s]*)[^\s]+");
```

Comment: Sry this is not what I want..!! I want to match the above strings from set of other strings and move to another file..!!

Comment: if you have all strings with you, why you using reg ex then?

Comment: Strings are in that form. like combination of " _ " " ." and " # " and some strings may not contain these I want to separate these kind of strings from normal words..